# Kendo MVC Grid Filtering Expected token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

im using the default Html.Kendo().Grid helper class

all my functions work like paging and sorting and grouping but every time i try to use the filtering i get

```
Exception Details: Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.FilterParserException: Expected token
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the code for how the grid is being set up and are you applying any custom filter properties to the grid before the data is being loaded?